# Abstract Quilt Square

Tags: java

I am creating an abstract quilt square. This will have a subclass of either an AbstractQuiltSection or an AbstractGraphicalQuiltSection and my class will extend one of these classes.

Since I am creating a text based quilt section, I extended the AbstractQuiltSection class.

There are nine abstract methods in AbstractQuiltSection:

```
**public abstract string line1...line9 (int width)**
```

Each of these methods will return a string. The length of the string should be the width parameter. I.e. if width is 12, the string returned should be exactly 12 characters long. The line1 method returns the first line of the quilt section, the line2 method returns the second line, etc.

#### Here is where I get confused:

Each text based quilt section will be 9 characters high (I.e. will take up 9 lines), but its width may vary. When the quilt is drawn, your line1, line2, line3…etc. methods will be called to figure out what characters to output.

A sample quilt section with a width of 12 (containing a quote from Shakespeare) might be:

```
............

.To.........

......Thine.

...own......

.....self...

..be........

.....true...

............

Shakespeare.
```

I have to create a subclass of AbstractQuiltSection that specializes 9 methods. 
In addition, you may specialize the textColor and backgroundColor methods to specify the colors on your text based quilt section.

Could anyone check if I did it right?

#### QuiltSquare

```
public class TomHakQuiltSquare extends AbstractQuiltSection {
    public static void main (String[]args){     

        AbstractQuiltSection square1 = new AbstractQuiltSection(); //Cannot instantiate the type AbstractQuiltSection
        square1.line1(12);
    }

    @Override
    public String line1(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String line2(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String line3(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String line4(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String line5(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String line6(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String line7(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String line8(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String line9(int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### AbstractQuiltSection

```
import java.awt.*;
public abstract class AbstractQuiltSection extends AbstractGraphicalQuiltSection {
    public abstract String line1(int width);
    public abstract String line2(int width);
    public abstract String line3(int width);
    public abstract String line4(int width);
    public abstract String line5(int width);
    public abstract String line6(int width);
    public abstract String line7(int width);
    public abstract String line8(int width);
    public abstract String line9(int width);

    public Color textColor(){
        return Color.black;
    }
    public Color backgroundColor(){
        return Color.white;
    }

    public void drawQuiltSection(Graphics g, int width, int height) {
        Font f;
        final int borderPix = 3;
        double fontHeight = (double) (height - borderPix*2)/9.0;
        f = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, (int)fontHeight);

        g.setColor(backgroundColor());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width+5, height+5);

        g.setColor(textColor());
        g.setFont(f);

        FontMetrics FM = g.getFontMetrics();
        int characters = (int) ((width - 2*borderPix)/FM.charWidth('0'));

        g.drawString(line1(characters), borderPix, height - borderPix - 8 * (int) FM.getAscent());
        g.drawString(line2(characters), borderPix, height - borderPix - 7 * (int) FM.getAscent());
        g.drawString(line3(characters), borderPix, height - borderPix - 6 * (int) FM.getAscent());
        g.drawString(line4(characters), borderPix, height - borderPix - 5 * (int) FM.getAscent());
        g.drawString(line5(characters), borderPix, height - borderPix - 4 * (int) FM.getAscent());
        g.drawString(line6(characters), borderPix, height - borderPix - 3 * (int) FM.getAscent());
        g.drawString(line7(characters), borderPix, height - borderPix - 2 * (int) FM.getAscent());
        g.drawString(line8(characters), borderPix, height - borderPix - 1 * (int) FM.getAscent());
        g.drawString(line9(characters), borderPix, height - borderPix);
    }
}
```